# How can I get a list of built-in texture names in Ursina

Tags: python-3.x, ursina

I'm new to use Ursina engine and I think is very well, but i wish to use built-in texture:

```
load_texture('texture_name')
```

but for now I only found 'withe_cube', is not very much, isn't it?

Please, where or how can I find a built-in texture names list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a list of all of them here: https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet_dark.html#textures

You could also go to `{Where you installed python}/Python/Lib/site-packages/ursina/textures/` on your system to find all the images.